# Wrong logs with spaces

Tags: shell

I use a Arduino, and log the result in a text file.
It's the result of the voltage from a thermocouple vs a Lm35.

Because I enjoy the log to be easily readable, I insert spaces in the Arduino code:

```
Serial.println("Lm35   Lm35_raw   thermocouple ADC  temp_thermocouple : ");
Serial.print(temp_Lm35);
Serial.print("  ");
Serial.print(lecture_Lm35);
Serial.print("        ");
Serial.print(lecture_thermocouple);
Serial.print("                ");
Serial.println(temp_thermocouple);
```

This gives:

```
Lm35   Lm35_raw   thermocouple ADC  temp_thermocouple : 
24.03  228        18                31.50
```

Then I need to use them in gnuplot.
So I clean the logs with

```
cat thermocouple_brut.log | grep -v  "[[:alpha:]]"  | awk 'NF<=4' | sort -t"." -k 1 -u -g  > thermocouple_propre.log
```

The result is:

```
107.06  1016        417                91.21
981        386                87.18
983        388                87.44
1012        415                90.95
```

Which makes no sense.

And of course gnuplot as a lot of problems reading this.

```
"./graphique.gnuplot" line 38: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

Line 38 is:

```
plot "thermocouple_propre.log" using  ($1):($4) title 'Thermocouple ' with lines lw 2 lc rgb"orange"
```

So I suppose my script to clean the logs is wrong, and I may need to remove the "spaces". They are "spaces", not "tab".

Comment: Just my curiosity... why you sort the file?

Comment: I use gnuplot to draw a curve, so the values need to be in the correct order.

Comment: I thought that data was already ordered by ascending time, and that that order is the one that you want. Anyway, I suspect that sort(1) does not do what you want, perhaps because you indicate the dot (decimal separator) as field separator. Some more (brief but complete) outputs could help to identify the problem.